# Arrow tube with flat arrowhead

Tags: graphics3d

I'm trying to create an animation which includes a spinning 3D arrow, but the arrowhead appears to be flat:

```
Manipulate[
  Show[
    ListPointPlot3D[{{Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 0}}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}, {-700, 1000}}, 
      PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.05], Black}, 
      Axes -> False, 
      Boxed -> False, 
      ImageSize -> 500, 
      AspectRatio -> 1], 
    Graphics3D[
      Scale[
        {Orange, Arrowheads[0.0003], Thickness[0.006], 
         Arrow[Tube[{{Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 0}, {Cos[θ], Sin[θ], -500}}, 0.03], -2]}, 
        {1, 1, 1}, {Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 0}]], 
    ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi, 1}], 
  {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

I tried changing all the possible range, the aspect ratio, the viewpoint, the size of the arrowhead, as well as inserting a cone as the style of the arrowhead, but they all end up looking flat or just disappearing. I'm not sure if it is just carefully picking the parameters of one of the options that I've already tried or there's something completely different that should be done?

Answer (score 1):

`Cone` can be used for the top of the arrow:

```
Manipulate[
  Show[
    ListPointPlot3D[{{Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 0}}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}, {-700, 1000}}, 
      PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.05], Black},
      Axes -> False,
      Boxed -> False,
      ImageSize -> 500,
      AspectRatio -> 1],
    Graphics3D[
     {Cylinder[{{Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 0}, {Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 500}}, .05], 
      Cone[{{Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 500}, {Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 800}}, .08]}], 
    ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi, 1}],
  {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image]